# saving file in databricks r language

Tags: r

In notebooks with databricks/azure r language, I create output files. How I can save these output files to local directory outside of databricks or open these files in databricks?

Example - I create plotly html plot

```
library(plotly)
fig <- plot_ly(data = iris, x = ~Sepal.Length, y = ~Petal.Length)
fig
```

In r studio, when I type "fig", the file automatically opens by itselfs. In databricks notebook I configure and set up cluster compute cores and permissions, then run r code which works. But in databricks notebook, when I type "fig", nothing happen.

I also try to save to my computer - like

```
list.files(path = getwd(), recursive = TRUE,full.names=TRUE)
saveWidget(fig, file = "dbfs:/path/to/fig.html")
save_html(fig, file = "dbfs:/path/to/mfig.html")
saveWidget(fig, file = paste0(getwd(),"/fig.html"))
```

I also try but not work

```
dbutils.fs.cp("dbfs:/path/to/fig.html", "file:/path/to/local/directory/gif.html")

local_path <- paste0(getwd(), "/fig.html")
dbutils.fs.cp("dbfs:/path/to/fig.html", paste0("file:", local_path))
```

How to automatically get databricks to save and view?

Comment: You can save files in the DBFS FileStore. The path needs to match that location and any subfolders need to exist under FileStore. So `write.csv(mtcars, file = "dbfs:/FileStore/test/mtcars.csv")` writes the file `mtcars.csv` into folder `Filestore/test` (assuming `test` exists).

Comment: thx! is there some automatic way i can find name of default folder? for example, in base r there is getwd function .... can i make? write.csv(mtcars, file = paste0("dbfs:/" , getwd, "mtcars.csv"))?

Comment: is there some way to automatically send file to databricks default folder .... and some way to send file to local computer outside of azure databricks? thx!

Comment: last question lol! is there some special way to open/view html file in databricks? in rstudio, file opens by itself when u type in its name ....suppose my file name is fig... in databricks, do i need to write view(fig), open(fig), display(fig)? thx!

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "databricks default folder". As I said, `FileStore` is the folder within DBFS where you can save files. `FileStore` files can be downloaded to local. Not sure what you are trying to achieve with `getwd()`. If you don't want to work with Databricks Notebooks, you can also connect to Databricks from a local RStudio instance.

Comment: how can i move file from filestore to local computer?

Comment: do you know how i can view html file within databricks?

Comment: Please have a look at the official documentation which is quite extensive and detailed. [`FileStore`](https://docs.databricks.com/dbfs/filestore.html) on how to access/download files from within `FileStore`; [`htmlwidgets`](https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/visualizations/htmlwidgets.html) on how to generate interactive plots (e.g. using `plotly`) from within Databricks; [`RStudio on Databricks`](https://docs.databricks.com/sparkr/rstudio.html) on how to connect local RStudio to Databricks.